# Parse content from URL itself in JSON format

Tags: android, json, parsing, url

**url:**'http://xyz/index.php/api/Users/?filter=[{"property":"vcUserName","value":"qwerty","operator":"="}]'

Can anyone please say me the way to parse data from such URL which is in JSON format

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: replace double quotes with \" in url and get the json content from the url using substring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send an HTTP request and fetch the response i.e. query result.  Once you have got your 'result' you can create JSONObject:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

Use this jObject to get different types using the specific names:

String:

```
String jsonString = jObject.getString("NAME");
```

Array:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("NAME");
```

Eg. For parsing the places results I used following function, where JSON is something like:

```
  "results" : [
 {
 "geometry" : {
    "location" : {
       "lat" : 36.817729,
       "lng" : 10.18206
    }
 },
 "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
 "id" : "35a4f720fff88e2cfb94d64bfd7dbe95a8b4a632",
 "name" : "Banque Al-Baraka",
 "reference" : "CoQBcwAAAJbocdTKVg8I8CzgDdNtBQQaMsaghRlks-IWYl9eDNmFtftPHMgEfVeek_NHJZ2AN9JbiMda1WvREmoeIHBHsNdz9i7gtBaLM1xB93uhema_oswpqD-eRQ9b3fvTo4MhTOeIa7cRJ70BSEtDMONZqFyjqlGvL-5WsiwmqI1F3Vp_EhArWzyFuNrJdly2cHRBNxUJGhQjlcyHs-U2F0ILpN-ce-PHEesdqA",
 "types" : [ "bank", "finance", "establishment" ],
 "vicinity" : "88 P9, Tunis"
 },
 {
 "geometry" : {
    "location" : {
       "lat" : 36.861635,
       "lng" : 10.164628
    }
 },
 "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
 "id" : "da42093835270f902f64bc870154e6787fffbc7b",
 "name" : "Agence Ennasr",
 "reference" : "CnRwAAAAoh-XuMXghUKtv2UtHQJiRXB0ZugUnAkJIyP-vBd2YzTj5GdwIb5XhUS9x5-uY9_OwyQUdMmUeDHYm4KXHFNvOoj7diOOHAGBu-xCI4svIxcCwQ2w063mc2G3lohiScYMNpbKhwnCaggt0H1iknZY6xIQxDvNwVN0wWkVwO8zf_El5hoUwHgmgFflE31LDLj2_rr0uc1zvZM",
 "types" : [ "bank", "finance", "establishment" ],
 "vicinity" : "Avenue de Hédi Nouira, Ariana"
 },
  ]
```

**Parsing JSON Array**

```
  public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> parseResult(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException         {        
     JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Constants.RESULTS);
     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        Object object = jsonArray.get(i);
        if (object instanceof JSONObject) {
            placesList.add(parsePlaceInfo((JSONObject) object));
        }
     }
    return placesList;
```

}

**Parsing simple JSON Object**

```
private HashMap<String, String> parsePlaceInfo(JSONObject place) throws JSONException {
    String name = place.getString(Constants.NAME);
    String icon = place.getString(Constants.ICON);
    String vicinity = place.getString(Constants.VICINITY);
    JSONObject locationObject = place.getJSONObject(Constants.GEOMETRY).getJSONObject(Constants.LOCATION);
    String lat = locationObject.getString(Constants.LAT);
    String lng = locationObject.getString(Constants.LNG);
    HashMap<String, String> placeDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
    placeDetails.put(Constants.NAME, name);
    placeDetails.put(Constants.ICON, icon);
    placeDetails.put(Constants.VICINITY, vicinity);
    placeDetails.put(Constants.LAT, lat);
    placeDetails.put(Constants.LNG, lng);

   return placeDetails;
}
```

Please check my answer here for further information on making HTTP request and parsing response:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872643/about-json-parsing-exchange-data-with-rest-services/21872688#21872688

There is a good JSON parsing [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) available online.

Let me know if you need any specific details.  Thanks!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Nanne Added details.  Hope its useful.  Thanks!